# conditions for lack of entophy in ThreadLocalRandom

Tags: netty

can anyone here help shed some light on the conditions under which the "Failed to generate a seed from SecureRandom within 3 seconds. Not enough entrophy" warning message is printed from ThreadLocalRandom?

we're able to consistently trigger the warning when hitting the server in a tight loop.  Everything still works, albeit with the 3s pauses, though I know *that* has been resolved (https://github.com/netty/netty/commit/3921f7c88a8db4feb45df89b0b28b3a9898993ab).

We'd like to modify our setup to avoid getting into these situations.  I'm not very familiar with the Netty codebase, but a quick grep and scan yields that it seems to be used for the channel Id in `DefaultChannelId`.  If those are assigned for each incoming request, I can see how that might exhaust the local pool of entropy.  If that's the case, can we use a different id mechanism for channels?

Comment: The seed generation is performed only once.  Once seed is acquired, it never uses `SecureRandom`, so you should never see that warning message more than once in the same process. If that's not the case, please file an issue.

Answer (score 3):

It could happen if you have a lot of worker threads, and at the beginning each request hits a different worker thread, causing it to ask for a new seed from `SecureRandom`.

**Update:**

One thread should not need more than 8 bytes from `SecureRandom`, but the available entropy on VMs can be really low. This is how you can test it:

```
cat /proc/sys/kernel/random/entropy_avail
```

And this is a page that convinced me I should always use `/dev/urandom`:

http://www.2uo.de/myths-about-urandom/

There are many options to increase the entropy estimate for `/dev/random` stop blocking, like [haveged](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Haveged) or [virtio-rng](http://rhelblog.redhat.com/2015/03/09/red-hat-enterprise-linux-virtual-machines-access-to-random-numbers-made-easy/#more-738), but in the end the distinction between `/dev/random` and `/dev/urandom` is very artificial, so you might as well use `/dev/urandom`.

Comment: The suggestion in that SO post is what we've used in our scripts that generate these errors.  There's a corresponding issue filed with Netty for this issue:  https://github.com/netty/netty/issues/3419

Comment: Is there a simple way of increasing entropy, for when you do not control the code that bumps into this, i.e. when using Play Framework?

Comment: The simplest option is `sudo mv /dev/random /dev/random_bak ; sudo ln -s /dev/urandom /dev/random`